# what does the fuse location string means (LocationClient)

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, coordinates

When I use LocationtClient to get my coordinates, The system send me this string :

```
Location[fused 19.364402,-99.178551 acc=96 et=+22h44m2s570ms alt=2275.0 vel=0.5 bear=17.0]
```

I understand fused is the coordinates, acc the accuracy, alt is the altitude, and vel my spped.

Is the accuracy in meters???
What is bear???

Also, I would think if I let the GPS searching, acc goes from big to small, but it isn't linear.
In some experiences, I had : acc : 596 -> 99 -> 20 -> 120 -> 35 -> 245...

I don't understand this, it should be always less otherwise it doesn't make sense to wait....

Is this information trustable???

Answer (score 0):

> Is the accuracy in meters??? What is bear???

Accuracy is in metres and is basically your horizontal accuracy. Bear is short for bearing which is in degrees.

> Also, I would think if I let the GPS searching, acc goes from big to
>   small, but it isn't linear. In some experiences, I had : acc : 596 ->
>   99 -> 20 -> 120 -> 35 -> 245...
>
> I don't understand this, it should be always less otherwise it doesn't
>   make sense to wait....

In this case I would say the GPS/Cellular/WiFi was having a tough time getting a fix on you. If it had a good fix on you you would expect them to be linear however in your case the locations were bouncing around.

> Is this information trustable???

You can trust the accuracy reading on the location. When you get a few accurate locations in a row then you can probably accept that you have a good location fix.